# How to read video dataset in tensorflow/keras?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to develop simple 3D-CNN network for the task of video classification. I'm having 6 categories with 100 videos for each category.
How can I pre-process this data and feed to the model?
And even how to read video dataset through the directory?